# How to extract characters from strings of varying length based on their position?

Tags: r

I'm going bald trying to figure this out. I am trying to extract characters from strings of varying length based on position. For example, lets say I have a data frame with 8 rows and 1 column titled: "Time"
The column has the following values in each row:

```
TIME
5  
20 
100
105
150
1050
2005
2010
```

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the characters in these strings and into the following format based on position. If you look, you can see that the last two characters are placed **00:here:00**  while all other characters are placed **here:00:00**. The result should be:

5     ->   00:05:00    (If there's only 1 characters) 
20    ->   00:20:00    (If there are 2 characters)
100   ->   1:00:00     (If there are 3 characters) 
105   ->  1:05:00      (If there are 3 characters)
150   -> 1:50:00        (If there are 3 characters) 
1050  -> 10:50:00       (If there are 4 characters) 
2005  -> 20:05:00       (If there are 4 characters) 
2010  -> 20:10:00       (If there are 4 characters)

Essentially the pseudo code would be something along the lines of
from dataframe$column1 extract the last two characters and place it **00:here:00** - all remaining characters should go **here:00:00**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
format( as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", TIME), format="%H%M"), format="%H:%M:%S")
[1] "00:05:00" "00:20:00" "01:00:00" "01:05:00"
[5] "01:50:00" "10:50:00" "20:05:00" "20:10:00"
```

The `sprintf` pads the character values of hte time variable with leading 0's. The `as.POSIXct` reads in the time as the current date with that time and then the outer `format.POSIXt` function removes the date characters.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I needed. The code is simple to read and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

What about this approach?

```
time <- readLines(n = 8)
5
20
100
105
150
1050
2005
2010
sub("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2:00", sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(time)))
# [1] "00:05:00" "00:20:00" "01:00:00" "01:05:00" "01:50:00" "10:50:00" "20:05:00" "20:10:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
library(stringr)
TIME <- c('5','20','100','105','150','1050','2005','2010')
TIMEpadded <- paste0(str_pad(TIME, width=4, pad=0), '00')
sub('(.+)(.{2})(.{2})', '\\1:\\2:\\3', TIMEpadded)
## [1] "00:05:00" "00:20:00" "01:00:00" "01:05:00" "01:50:00" "10:50:00" "20:05:00" "20:10:00"
```

Comment: You don't need `stringr` and you could do `paste0(sprintf("%04d", df$TIME), "00")` instead.

Comment: `sprintf("%04d00", df$TIME)` even (or `as.integer(df$TIME)` if required), no need for `paste`.

Comment: Yes, that's a even nicer

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static String transform (String in)
{
    while (in.length() < 4)
    {
        in = "0" + in;
    }
    in = in.substring(0,2) + ":" + in.substring(2,4) + ":00";
    return(in);
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    for (String s : new String[]{"5", "20", "100", "105", "150", "1050", "2005", "2010"})
    {
        System.out.println(s + " -> " + transform(s));
    }
}
```

The method transform:
1) adds zeros to a time value in the string in, till obtaining a 4-digits string.
2) inserts ":" each two characters in the string and a trailing "00".

The method main runs the example you provided,
with the following output:

```
5 -> 00:05:00
20 -> 00:20:00
100 -> 01:00:00
105 -> 01:05:00
150 -> 01:50:00
1050 -> 10:50:00
2005 -> 20:05:00
2010 -> 20:10:00
```

Comment: Wrong language. Also, the desired output was just for illustration, they don't rally trying to print the arrow.